# Implementing Custom Preloader animation for Loading heavy assets in React-JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, assets, preloading

I am currently developing a React-JS application that features a substantial amount of assets, including videos and images, some of which are conditionally rendered based on user interaction, such as hovering or clicking a button. Due to which, the webpage is experiencing significant performance issues.

To enhance the user experience, I am looking for a solution to display a preloader screen with a custom animation upon the user's initial landing on the website. During this preloading phase, I want to load all the assets, ensuring seamless performance when the user interacts with the actual content.

I have observed this approach on several awwward websites, and I am looking for guidance on implementing a native React-JS solution (without TypeScript) or recommendations for a suitable library that can help me implement this functionality. **Additionally, I would like to show an accurate progress bar to visually represent the loading status of the assets.**

As suggested by a few people and Chat-GPT, I tried placing my preloader screen (along with the progress animation) inside of  within index.html and also lazy loading the assets. But eventually realized that **these techniques don't work as per my expectations.**

Could you please suggest a method or library that aligns with these requirements? Any code snippets or examples illustrating the implementation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!